# How to reset post data properly

Tags: theme-development, get-posts, wp-reset-postdata

I have this piece of code that I am calling within the loop to get image metadata ( title/caption and description ). It works fine but it only works for the first post in the loop. So I assume it needs to be reset. From looking here I think `wp_rest_postdata();` is the right way to reset the query, but still the output fails for all but the first post, it repeats the data from the first post for every other post.

```
function get_image_metadata() {

    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'include'  => $image_id
        ); 
    $image_data = get_posts($args);

    if ($image_data && isset($image_data[0])) {
        $meta_output['title'] = $image_data[0]->post_title; 
        $meta_output['caption'] =  $image_data[0]->post_excerpt; 
        $meta_output['description'] =  $image_data[0]->post_content; 
    }
    //wp_reset_query();
    wp_rest_postdata();
    return $meta_output;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the template-file/loop context in which this function is *called*, for reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) you don't actually *setup* post data unless you do so explicitly, via [`setup_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) inside your (usually a `foreach`) loop.

So, since you're not setting up post data, you shouldn't need to *reset* post data.

> but still the output fails for all but the first post

I *think* that's because you're calling the global `$post` inside your function, but aren't *globalizing* it first:

```
$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'include'  => $image_id
    ); 
$image_data = get_posts($args);
```

Try adding `global $post;` before using `$post->ID`:

```
global $post;
$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'include'  => $image_id
    ); 
$image_data = get_posts($args);
```

If that's not the problem, can you clarify:

1. What data you get from `$iamge_data`
2. The context in which you are calling the function

Comment: I had tried that but it didnt work either. The difference between globalizing $post and not is that when I don't I get the first post's output repeated for every other post and when I do I get a null output for those other posts. Actually I'm going to edit my question a bit because I think I had that wrong in there. The data I am getting is the caption, description and title of the attached image. The context I use it in is that I am calling it from within the look in content-image.php ( image post format )

Comment: Actually my answer to your question got me thinking and I realised what the problem is. The code was actually fine, it displays the information for the featured image, not the attached image - I forgot I was using `get_post_thumbnail_id` , and in the other posts there were no featured images. (Yet at the same time I was displaying either featured or attached ; whichever the code found first ) ... when I added featured images to the posts it all worked fine, or at least I know what the problem was.

Comment: Score! Glad you figured it out. :)